# Tweepy - Error 144 when populating a pandas dataframe column with tweet strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tweepy

I'm populating some rows in a dataframe using the twitter ID. I've run the script the first time without the *except* and I had the error:
`[{'code': 144, 'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}]`
I understand that it might be because someone deleted the tweet or for other reason. However, I need to keep going!

So I used the `except: pass`, but it actually doesn't return anything. All the rows are empty. I've been working hard on this, but I don't know to solve it.

My dataframe:

```
          TweetID                text               pageType
index   
id1                     My code is not working      http://blablabla.com
id2     451864165416    Nan                         twitter
id3     849849849844    Nan                         twitter
```

Here is the code that doesn't return anything:

```
try:
    if (df['pageType'] == 'twitter').any:
        df['text'] = df.tweetID.apply(lambda x: api.get_status(x).text)
except:
    pass
```

That's it!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a *boolean index* + `loc` + `apply`:

```
mask = df['pageType'] == 'twitter'
df.loc[mask, 'text'] = df.loc[mask, 'twitterID']\
                           .apply(lambda x: api.get_status(x).text)
```

Comment: Thanks, @coldspeed. That definitely looks better, but unfortunately, I'm getting the same error :/ Cheers!

Comment: @MoniqueMarins no worries. I see a try-except can’t be avoided. I’ll provide a fix in a bit, so hang on.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, your `try` and `except` setup stops execution before the `apply` can be completed, which in turn never creates the new column. Typically you would place this clause in a `for-loop`, the way you are using it. Instead you could create a custom function, so that it catches errors on `tweetID` values that are invalid.

```
def GetStuff(value):
    try:
        return api.get_status(value).text
    except:
        return "ERROR"

df['text'] = df.tweetID.apply(lambda x: GetStuff(x))
```

---

To meet the conditions in the comments:

**Option 1**

```
def GetStuff(value):
    try:
        return api.get_status(value).text
    except:
        return "ERROR"

df['text'] = df.where(df.tweetID == 'twitter').tweetID.apply(lambda x: GetStuff(x))
```

Which applies the function where `tweetID` == `twitter`, the the other values are `NaN` with you can replace with some other text using `fillna()`

**Option 2**

Build conditions in the `GetStuff()` function.

```
def GetStuff(value):
    if value == 'twitter':
        try:
            return api.get_status(value).text
        except:
            return "ERROR"
     else:
         return 'NotTwitter'

df['text'] = df.tweetID.apply(lambda x: GetStuff(x))
```

Comment: Thanks. That works fine. However, I'm filling in the 'text' column and I don't want to return "ERROR" if the 'pageType' is not 'twitter'. For instance, I want to return the string that is in row 1 and also look up and fill in row 2 and 3 with the GetStuff function. Finally, if it doesn't work then I return "ERROR". Is it possible or do I need to break down into smaller steps?